# cardinality of empty list union empty list

Tags: discrete-mathematics

{∅, {{∅}}} ∪ {{∅}} ∪ ∅
I had this question and they asked cardinality of the set
the elements inside sets are 3 however it is union with empty set outside so what is cardinality of this set?
I think the answer is 3 but I want to make sure if I'm true or no.

Comment: you are right :-) However, your justification is not so convincing. For example $\{\varnothing ,\{\varnothing \}\}\cup\{\{\varnothing \}\}\cup\varnothing $ have cardinality be $2$... but probably you were aware of that.

Comment: can you clarify why this is 2?

Comment: because $\{\varnothing ,\{\varnothing \}\}\cup\{\{\varnothing \}\}=\{\varnothing ,\{\varnothing \}\}$.

Comment: where did the third ∅ goes this? why did we declined it here

Comment: Say $a=\varnothing $ and $b=\{\varnothing \}$. Now, my previous comment is exactly $\{a,b\}\cup\{b\}$ which is nothing else than $\{a,b\}$ :-)

Comment: it seems that i got it 3 by luck because depending on your explanation now i dont know why it is 3

Comment: Because if $a=\varnothing $, $b=\{\varnothing \}$ and $c=\{\{\varnothing \}\}$, the set you proposed is $\{a,c\}\cup \{b\}\cup \varnothing =\{a,b,c\}$

Comment: oh i see i see now i got it thanks so much for your helping!!!!